# Хранение "быстрых" версий вопросов и ответов

Tags: обсуждение, правки

Недавно увидел только что опубликованный вопрос [Как получить сумму цифр числа с учётом знака: -35 -> -3 + 5 -> 2?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542406/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0/542408#542408) и решил быстренько на него ответить (каюсь, захотелось "по-легкому" срубить репы). Позже зашел и удивился, что за ответ дали несколько "плюсов". Еще позже получил минус. Стал разбираться и увидел что мой ответ не подходит под приведенный автором вопроса пример. Но также я, вроде бы, помню что такого примера в вопросе не было, хотя в версиях вопроса есть только тексты с примером.

Как теперь понять, это я меня в голове глюк или автор быстро отредактировал вопрос и версия с примером заменила "недописанную" версию без примера?

PS. Кстати по поводу таких быстрых правок без сохранения в истории предыдущих версий в справке ничего не обнаружено, но по опыту знаю, что этот функционал есть

Comment: на сколько я знаю правки укладывающиеся в *5 минутный диапазон* *сливаются* в  одну

Comment: Я тоже догадываюсь. Но вот как теперь понять, было там такое или нет?

Comment: *Но вот как теперь понять, было там такое или нет?* - для чего? либо смириться и удалить *некорректный* ответ, или же исправить его что бы он соответствовал вопросу, и ждать/надеяться что минуса уйдут. А впредь не пытаться срубить репы по *бырику* и не отвечать на не явные вопросы, или же быть готовым к минусам при внесении изменений т.с. ;)

Comment: @bald Ну как это "не пытаться" :) А минусы в таких количествах - это ну вообще не страшно. Мне просто стало любопытно, это я не туда посмотрел или вопрос поменялся

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/grace-period/info

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, правки вопроса _до_ данного ответа не сливаются с правками _после_. Но вопрос мог поменяться _во время_ написания ответа, да.

Comment: В ситуации с указанным вопросм есть интересный момент. Автор вопроса написал что ответ делает именно то, что нужно. Причем указал это в двух комментариях и отметил мой ответ как полезный/верный, но при этом мой ответ не работает как указано в примере

Comment: И это самое интересное. Спросите его об этом. Проясните, что же ему нужно и как он проверяет результат. Дополните свой ответ или помогите автору доработать вопрос. Имхо, в такой работе - самая большая ценность этого сайта.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Как мне кажется, ответ следующий](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21788/274323).

> Для того, чтобы избежать множества мелких правок в истории, автору сообщения дается 5-минутный период «свежей правки», за исключением случаев, когда новая или старая ревизия был отменена.
>
> Любые новые правки, вносимые в сообщение в течении этого периода, объединяются в одну и не отображаются в истории ревизий. Период свежей правки завершается ровно через 5 минут или если:
>
> - другой участник внес изменения в сообщение, начав свой период свежей правки;
> - с момента последней правки к сообщению был добавлен комментарий кем–либо кроме автора сообщения;
> - с момента последней правки к сообщению, являющемуся вопросом, был опубликован ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Для определённости предлагаю считать, что вопрос поменялся. Автор мог перечитать свой вопрос и понять, что требуется уточнение. Или мог дополнить вопрос после получения комментариев и первых ответов. Это нормальная рабочая ситуация.

Поэтому перед публикацией ответа и/или сразу после публикации полезно перечитать вопрос, комментарии к нему и чужие ответы. Иногда приходится удалить ответ, чтобы кардинально его переделать.

И да, правки, сделанные в течение пяти минут, объединяются в одну. Но они потому и объединяются, что автору нужно время, чтобы понять, о том ли он попросил, а отвечающему - чтобы проверить, на тот ли вопрос он ответил.

Comment: _"после получения комментариев"_ - не мог - тогда бы правка записалась независимо от времени. А вот про ответы не уверен.